# Sending Data from Django view to model

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

I have JSON variable which I can get from Javascript.I want to save it in database.I am not able to write exact view function for it

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from jsonfield import JSONField

    class update_grid(models.Model):
        data = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

My View.py

```
def save_grid(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    data = json.loads(request.body)# I want to send this variable to update_grid and save it

    return HttpResponse('success') # if everything is OK
```

When I check in admin no model named update_grid shows up.

Comment: If question needs any clarification please ask :)

Comment: I'm not sure where you're having problems. You have the value in `data`, what's stopping you saving it to the model?

Comment: I am not able to load the data in model.Also when I check the model in admin the given model does not exists

Comment: I just wanted to check the contents of json variable which I am loading through website but the model itself is not showing in admin

Comment: Even after spending ample amount of time I am still wondering where is the mistake happening.Is it in the `return HTTP` or declaration of Model itself ,dont know exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through your comments, and what you have posted, there are quite a things that might be missing, though I am unsure exactly what you have and have not done.

In your models file, you named your model update_grid, so you need to make sure that is added to your admin.py file in order for it to appear there.

I am not 100% sure you are loading in the JSONfield properly, but if it works then by all means. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield) is documentation on that though in case that is the problem. Traditionally, though you might want to parse the JSON object into specific fields that are stored in the model, but we all have different goals in mind.

In your views.py file, you will need to import your model if you have not already done so. After you receive the data, you need to then save it to your model. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) is a link on how to properly save, and it would look something like the following:

```
from .models import update_grid
data = json.loads(request.body)
grid = update_grid(data=data)
grid.save()
```

Hopefully this helps a bit, and if you need more help, just comment and I can try and help further. If you haven't done so already, though, I would recommend checking out a bit of the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/), as it might help clear up some of your confusion.

Comment: This helped a lot  1)I had not added model in admin 2)I had not done makemigrations and migrate

Comment: Glad I could help a bit :)

Comment: But now I am getting this error when I add json manually from Admin 
 `'update_grid' object has no attribute 'title'` `.

Comment: (Making an assumption here) I think that your JSON blob has a title field within it, and when you are doing json.loads(), it converts the string to JSON blob. I am uncertain again how that library works, I can try it out a bit later and report back, but you might need to look into how that library expects the data to be saved (as a JSON blob or a string or something else entirely?)

Comment: Should I mention a title in my models ? Is that what it wants

Comment: My json is of the format [{"col":1,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":3,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":4,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":1,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":3,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":4,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":1,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":3,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":4,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":5,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":6,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1}]

Comment: Is structure important? If all you want to do is see it, you could also just save this information in a TextField. Then you could just save the data as a string instead of converting it to JSON and handling that. I would need a bit more info to fully help you out though. Try using a TextField and see if that works better?

Comment: actually i get this data from gridster and i also want to retrieve it to load gridster next time.But its okay if we store it in text in database. as text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166302/discussion-between-rookie-123-and-coolestnerdiii).